# Windows 10 - Bash (Ubuntu) SU (Root Password)

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently updated to Windows 10, installed Ubuntu Bash. Wanted to start configuring, But I have hit a wall already.

When installed, you are asked for a username and password for your account. 
This creates a user level.

Is it possible to access to root user, SU?

Every time I try, it asks for a password, and none of the accounts on the PC work (i.e., Windows 10 admin account password does not work). Tried default passwords too etc., all fail.

The reason for it is when looking at the users home directory: When creating a file, it creates it under my Windows User Account (Permissions).

But when I view files created from Bash, they are created for Root user.

So this is the confusion, I modified `bashrc` and it's no longer owned by root, So it's not accessible.

But I cannot login to root to create or modify the files.

Am I being a complete noob or something?
[image]

When `bashrc` is not owned by Root, when loading `Bash.exe`, I get `.bashrc Input/output error`.

Comment: read http://www.howtogeek.com/261417/how-to-change-your-user-account-in-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/

Comment: lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y

Answer (score 167):

as far as i know you'll have to type "sudo su"

Comment: Thanks worked perfect *Facepalm* Feel abit numpty now!! Thanks for quick response

Comment: To change the default user to root without password, try "lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y" from cmd.exe

Comment: I personally get "sudo: unable to resolve host {MY COMPUTER NAME}" when I try to do this.

Comment: @buddyp450 had the same issue, check this post for help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none

Comment: sudo@bash@ubuntu@windows hangs if no Internet connection

Comment: ` sudo su root`  works all the time :)
And is needed just  change the passwd for root from there (I find  it a good practice)

Comment: why does `sudo su` work but `su` does not?

Comment: Why doesn't `su root` work?